# Spark Connectors for Cloudian/S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

Is there an option available to write bytes (of documents) into S3 Object storage using, if available, spark connectors.
Such need arouse from a data migration activity where the files are written as BLOB's into a relational database and the same now should go into S3 using Spark, however i dont see there's a connector that supports AFAIK.
Any pointers?